# Neural network to approximate the wanted solution of a system of differential equations

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have a target solution for a system of differential equations that has some unknown parameters.I want to find the values of these parameters for which the solution is closer to the target.Can I do this with neural networks?If yes,how?

I am asking this because a paper I'm reading (unfortunately in Greek) implies to be doing this very thing.
There is the following system of differential equations
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

The wanted output is 
[image]
and the control input u has some unknown non-linearities in it which it is stated that are approximated using neural networks. Since there is no data to train a network,I wasn;t able to understand how it is done? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so; the typical usage of a NN is to learn a pattern from a set of examples, so that it can properly classify examples it hasn't seen.  That description doesn't seem to fit your problem.

Update (after question was edited): I don't think the specifics of the equation are relevant.  As you say, there is no data with which to train a network, so it would be hard (if not impossible) to evaluate that aspect, as it might as well have been done by flipping coins.  Thus, I think you'd have to focus on the other aspects of the paper (assuming there are some).

Comment: Thanks for your answer...I have edited the question above!Could you take a look?

Comment: This is misleading. A NN is an *approximation tool*, and classification is only one of possible tasks NN can solve (for example, NNs are also used for time-series prediction). Refer to the [Universal approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem).

Comment: @BartoszKP What do you mean is misleading? The use of neural networks in the article is indeed supposed to be based on the universal approximation theorem. How can this be applied here?

Comment: @PavlosTriantafyllou All usages of NNs are based on this theorem, because it shows that they can work at all :) The misleading part of this answer is that it says that NNs are mainly about classifying examples. It is correct though with regard to the data: it's possible, but hard to imagine practical application of a NN without training data.

Comment: @BartoszKP: And if one has a paper purporting to do just that, you'd think it would be crystal clear to any reader.